# Optimal storage for fast read/write

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm wondering and I want to do this the properly. I have bunch of data about 5 lines of data such as api keys, site name, remote service addresses.

Now there's two options I'm considering but i want to go for the faster one. The application in mind is a e-shop that will hold about 50k products so load times will be effected by that. Now the data i need to store will be changed by application so i have the question:

Which is faster and better option. Keeping the data in a XML and reading and changing the XML file or keeping the data in a SQL table. Is it faster to read a very tiny xml file or run a SQL query and is it faster to rewrite xml file or run a update query.

Comment: Any Idea why Databases were invented? And XML's actual use?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the data in an "SQL table" is absurdly faster than XML. Please Google for examples.